# how to make menu ul li toggle with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to make a menu ul li that toggles open and close with some javascript. I have code as a link.

Section

- kategori

Section

- kategori
- kategori

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8qb468bu/

Answer (score 0):

It's really the nested ul you want to be showing, when you click the parent li, so your click handler was wrong, slightly. I also updated some styles to get this to work a little better.

https://jsfiddle.net/8qb468bu/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#categories li').click(function() {
      $(this).find('ul').toggleClass('selected'); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I meant :) Thanx for Ur help!

Comment: Have 1 more question for styling, how do I make section and kategories have a black background when its open and with a minus on the selected section? Look at picture https://billedeupload.dk/?v=3EzH.jpg